# jQuery element with href AND rel value

Tags: jquery, href, attr, rel

If we know that we can use

```
var link = $('a[href="http://google.com"]');
```

when we want to find a link with specified href attribute, and also

```
var link = $('a[rel="myrel"]');
```

when we want to find a link with specified rel attribute, how can we combine those two attributes so that is possible to find a link with a specified href AND rel in same time?

I have tried with

```
var link = $("a[rel='myrel', href='http://google.com']");
```

and

```
var link = $("a[rel='myrel'][href='http://google.com']");
```

and it didn't worked

Comment: The last one should work: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/LYRtr/

Comment: the last one works, try it here [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/86CWW/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var link = $('a[rel="myrel"][href="http://google.com"]');
```

This should work fine.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ScxTV/

Comment: I'd reverse the quotes though. Double-quotes are for HTML attribute values, and single-quotes for JavaScript strings. (That's my preference.)

Answer (score 0):

Your second example should work. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUeZK/).

```
<a href='http://thoughtresults.com' rel='nofollow'>Thought Results</a>
<a href='http:/www.google.com'>Google</a>

// This alerts 1
alert($('a[href=http://thoughtresults.com][rel=nofollow]').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

something else might be wrong its working here

http://jsfiddle.net/NquxJ/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var link = $('a[rel="myrel"][href="http://google.com"]');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your last code should work!

```
var link = $("a[rel='myrel'][href='http://google.com']");
```

Why not? Try on console. Should work.